# How to check a method executed in the unit test context?

Tags: java, junit

I am trying to add some features to the legacy libraries and plan to make it testable.

I want to limit some methods allowed call in the testing context, like change the global system configurations. Because some changes are dangerous for production, to limit the accessablitiy is important.

I use the junit4 to test my project, any suggestions for it?

```
class Foo {
    public void methodA() {
        // is it possible limit methodA only allowed invoked by JUNIT ?
    }
}
```

Comment: The title doesn't seem connected to the body of your question, please clarify.

Comment: "I want to limit some methods allowed call in the testing context" - also not very clear

Comment: I guess if you have some "dangerous" methods which should only be used in tests, not in production, then put them in classes which you then put in your src/test folder (if you use maven) or else exclude them from being packaged with production code. What is not there, cannot hurt.

Comment: In order to let my project testable, I add method to change the configuration settings, they are only for tests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would make a stub

```
    Lib l = new Lib() {
        @Override
        void xxx() {
            Assert.fail("calling xxx() is not allowed");
        }
    };
```

Comment: It looks good and inspried me to try reflection the junit packages

Answer (score 1):

The thing comes in my mind is to use dependency injection to use two different implementations of the same interface, one for production and one for testing. The one you inject in the production execution could just have empty method that doesn't actually do nothing. Concept:

```
class Foo {

    private Bar bar;

    public Foo() {

        bar = new DefultBarImplementation();
    }


    public setBar(Bar bar) {

        this.bar = bar;
    }

    //use bar in your other methods
}
```

In your tests

```
Foo foo = new Foo();
foo.setBar(new TestBarImplementation());
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I know use the different implementation is better. However, there are many untestable singleton pattern in my legacy project. Maybe it is time to fix them ....

Answer (score 0):

You can make the methods package-private and have the tests in the same package.

```
public class Foo{

    public void publicMethod();

    void forTestingOnly();

}
```